# Image ToolTip show on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've managed to make the tooltip show on mouse hover but I want it to show for click as well.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Pictures/question_mark.png" Tooltip="Hello" OnClick="Image2_OnClick" Height="16px" Width="16px" />

        protected void Image2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //int MilliSeconds = 5000;
        //ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
        //toolTip1.SetToolTip(TextBox1, "Hello");
        Image2.ToolTip.Show();
        //toolTip1.Show("Devices have been selected according to the package. Please untick the box if you already have the device.");
    }
```

I tried the above stuff but failed so far.

Help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: In ASP.Net the tooltip-property will render as html title-tag which is shown when user hovers over the html-element. This is a default browser feature. To show something on click needs a javascript implementation.

Comment: So a user hovers over the image, showing the tooltip, then when they click on the image you want to show it again?  Before the implementation, my first question would be why?